# java для самых маленьких \ таймеры

Tags: java, countdowntimer

Я только начал изучать такой язык программирования как Java.
Меня интересует как сделать таймер после какого либо события, например, после выведения сообщения на экран.
Хотел бы попросить вас помочь разобраться с этим вопросом на примере шутки.

```
class HackPentagon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( "Процесс взлома Пентагона запущен" ) ;
        System.out.println( "0%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        System.out.println( "34%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        System.out.println( "68%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        System.out.println( "98%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        System.out.println( "100%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        System.out.println( "Взлом прошел успешно" ) ;


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class HackPentagon {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println( "Процесс взлома Пентагона запущен" ) ;
        System.out.println( "0%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        System.out.println( "34%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        System.out.println( "68%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        System.out.println( "98%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        System.out.println( "100%" ) ;
        ///таймер на случайное значение от 0 до 5000
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        System.out.println( "Взлом прошел успешно" ) ;

    }
}
```

Comment: человек просил случайное значение, а не точное, можно улучшить чем-то вроде Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * (5000)));

Comment: Если случайное значение требуется несколько раз, может быть удобнее использовать класс Random. `static final Random RANDOM = new Random();` и `int pause = RANDOM.nextInt(5000);`.

Comment: @ Дмитрий Никифоров в этом варианте будет только одно случайное значение pause. Либо писать везде - RANDOM.nextInt(5000);

Comment: Да, разумеется.